# Left coset and right coset of subgroup $H=\langle(234)\rangle$ in alternating group $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

My homework question is:

> Partition $G=A_4$ into left cosets of the subgroup $H=\langle (234)\rangle$

but I am not sure how to start with.

I know that $$A_4= \{(1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23), (123), (132), (124), (142), (134), (143), (234), (243)\},$$ am I right?

Also, the left coset of H is $xH=\{xh:h\in H\}$.

Comment: About $A_4$ elements: You know that $|A_4|=\frac{4!}{2}=12$, so you got the right number. Concerning the elements that you have, you can check if the signature of each permutation is $-1$. And to get the left cosets of $H$, you simply compose each element of $A_4$ with all the elements of $\langle(234)\rangle$

Comment: And to get the left cosets of $H$, you simply compose each element of $A_4$ with all the elements of $\langle(234)\rangle$. For example for $x=Id\in A_4$ you obtain the following as left coset:  $xH=\{(234),(243),Id\}$. You do the same with each element of $A_4$ and you leave only different cosets. If i remember well, to check if yo got the right number of left cosets, you divide the cardinal of $A_4$ by the cardinal of $H$ (not sure about it anymore), so you will obtain $4$ left cosets

Answer (score 2):

A 3-cycle has order 3, and $A_4$ has order 12, so there will be four left cosets by Lagrange's theorem. Recall the Klein four group is a subgroup of $A_4$, and it intersects trivially with $C_3$ since their elements have different orders, so each element of $K_4$ induces a left coset of $C_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H=\{e,(234),(243)\}$, we get that the four right cosets are
$$\begin{align}
H, &\\
H(12)(34)&=\{(12)(34),(132),(142)\}, \\
H(13)(24)&=\{(13)(24),(143),(123)\},\\
H(14)(23)&=\{(14)(23),(124),(134)\},
\end{align}$$

just by multiplying through by the elements of $V_4$.  (I know that will get me the four cosets since $V_4\cap H=\{e\}$.)

Similarly for the left cosets.

Comment: The last two sentences are wrong.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks for pointing it out.  @ancientmathematician